# Como cambiar el tamaño de un ejecutable (width y height) con .bat

Tags: windows

Tengo un ejecutable pero no el codigo fuente, quiero que al ejecutarse se abra con la mitad de alto y la mitad de ancho, he buscado que se puede con un archivo .bat, pero no se ejecuta. Lo intente con display change que es una aplicacion para cambiar ejecutables con batch pero aun asi no funciona.
puse esto...

```
dc2.exe -width=400-height=300"C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\free\App.exe"
```

Comment: Capaz ese ejecutable no admite un cambio de tamaño?

Comment: Has probado con la propiedad `position`, y si puede ser que @gbianchi tenga razón y no habra forma de cambiarlo